# xorg.conf to choose one of Intel & NVIDIA or use both at the same time (not a optimus, separated two graphic)

Tags: nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I'm trying setting up xorg.conf to choose one of Intel & NVIDIA or use both at the same time, on a CentOS 7 machine.

My machine is just using separated two graphic - one is CPU-integrated(Xeon with graphic) and another is PCIe NVIDIA GeForce - and not a Optimus one.

What I want to do is run CUDA application on NVIDIA graphic card while using Intel integrated one as display output.